# How to map a database?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, sqlmetal

I've created a *.dbml file through sqlmetal tool, which contains a diagram of my database (MSSQL). But, my database has 266 tables and if I open that file in VS2008 and export it via PDF, I've got a terrible document. VS2010 will hung up when opening that file. I need to map this database because I need to create an external tool which will work with it. 
Is there some conventional approach to learn how this database is created ? I need to know how are the tables connected together (relations) in order to create a tool which will extract data from them.
Or, Is there some other tool which can read dbml files and visualize relations between those tables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going over dbml is probably a bad idea. Suggestions:

1. Reverse engineer using Visio.
2. Use the Sql Server diagramming tool, available in Sql Management Studio.
3. Run [dbdesc](http://www.dbdesc.com/) against the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Only for information - I've tried Visio 2010 Professional - it crashes everytime when it tries to reverse engeneer those 230 tables with their relations. Diagramming support in SQL Server 2005 is really helpfull in conjunction with dbdesc tool. Dbdesc is good, but it creates 1675 pages in pdf - so hard to print and remember :). But your answer is really a twist in a myth ! Thanks again.